# C: How to point to calloc array?

Tags: c, memory-management, calloc

I am trying to point a pointer to a calloc array. For some reason, when I reach the second element the program force quits. The first element prints out and works fine. Here is an example of my code just trying to print out all the elements through a second pointer:

```
integerArray = (int*)calloc(totalNum, sizeof(int));

if(integerArray == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR! Number entered is invalid.");
    exit(1);
}

collectNumbers(totalNum, integerArray);

arrayAscending = &integerArray;
arrayDescending = &integerArray;

for(i = 0; i < totalNum; i++)
{
    printf("%3d", **(arrayAscending + i));
}
```

Comment: I'm using just regular C.

Comment: In future, please show your variable declarations.  Presumably, you have `int *integerArray;` and `int **arrayAscending;` and `int **arrayDescending;` (and `int i;`, and `int totalNum;`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
printf("%3d", **(arrayAscending + i));
```

You are incrementing a pointer to pointer.

In accordance to the code that I see here, it supposed to be the following:

```
printf("%3d", *((*arrayAscending) + i)));
```

The first of all you should dereference the `arrayAscending` in order to get the pointer `integerArray` value and only after this increment it if you do not want use the indexing.

You can also write as follows:

```
printf("%3d",(*ayyarAscending)[i]);
```

But actually more simple is just using indexing:

```
printf("%3d", integerArray[i]);
```

Comment: `(*ayyarAscending)[i]` also might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayAscending = &integerArray;   // these point to the int*, they don't get the value...
arrayDescending = &integerArray;

for(i = 0; i < totalNum; i++)
{
    printf("%3d", integerArray[i]);  // FIXED
}
```